# How can I determine where an error message printed during shell startup comes from?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker

After uninstall Docker on Ubuntu, each time I start a bash shell window, it emits the following hint:

```
The program 'docker' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
    sudo apt install docker.io
```

I have searched in `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, but didn't found any lines related to docker.

So, how can I get rid of those tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i` to log every command in your startup scripts, including which config file or script they came from. Search through that, and you'll find the individual command that's creating this error.

<sub>*(Note that very new versions of bash ignore inherited values of `PS4` when running as root for security reasons. But you're not using `root` as your primary account... right?)*</sub>

Comment: I executed the command, but can't pipe it with ` | less -N` or ` > result.txt`. So how to save the result to a file for easy searching?

Comment: It's on stderr by default (configurable, in bash 4.0 or later, with the `BASH_XTRACEFD` variable). `2>` will redirect it, or you can just use `bash -x -l -i 2>&1 | less`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it turns out it's an alias command I defined before that cause the issue: `alias drmexit="docker rm $(docker ps -q -f status=exited)"`. After comment out this line, the tip gone.

Comment: So, this is one of the places where aliases and functions differ in important ways: Your alias only ran `docker ps` when your shell started up and recorded its output in the alias; when you ran `drmexit`, it just reused that prior output. You wouldn't have that bug if you used a function: `drmexit() { docker rm $(docker ps -q -f status=exited) "$@"; }` runs `docker ps` at execution time, not at shell startup time.

Comment: (You could also change the quoting type used during the alias definition, but just switching to a function is the best practice in general unless one has a very specific reason why an alias is the right thing. Such reasons are rare -- I think I've seen maybe three or four cases where an alias is more appropriate than a function in the entirety of my career).

Comment: Just tested it, if I changed the quote to `'` instead of `"`, it also emit the output, nice! It's great to know these practice principles. I also wrote another alias for testing `alias lsdir='ls -l $(pwd)'`, it works correctly when switching dirs, while quote `"` won't, works exactly as the your comment described, didn't notice these tricks before.

Comment: As another aside -- `"$PWD"` is more efficient than `"$(pwd)"` (and also more correct in some odd cases, like directory names that end in literal newlines);  both of those are more correct than `$(pwd)` without the quotes, which will fail with any directory name with a space in it. And in the specific case of `ls -l`, the current directory is *default*, so I wouldn't usually expect there to be much reason to pass it an explicit name at all.